# Проблемы с выходом за рамки двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Вот моя инициализация динамического двумерного массива 3 на 3 :

```
double** A = (double**)calloc(3, sizeof(double*));
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
    A[i] = (double*)calloc(3, sizeof(double));
}
```

Когда я вывожу содержимое динамического двумерного массива в терминал с размерами, обратите внимание, 4 на 3, то мне выдаётся Segmentation fault, это понятно.

Но(!) когда я вывожу содержимое динамического двумерного массива в терминал с размерами, вновь обратите внимание, 3 на 4, да хоть 3 на 20, то Segmentation fault не выдаётся, вместо этого в терминале следующее :

```
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

С чем это связано, ведь я, так или иначе, выхожу за рамки массива? Почему мне не выдаёт в терминале Segmentation fault?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Да потому что вы разыменовываете "нормальный" указатель на какую-то доступную программе память, а потом по нему уже гуляете по памяти (с выходом за границы массива, но 20 — это недалеко, так что этот блок памяти программе доступен)... А в 4 на 3 четвертый указатель — это совершенно "левое" значение, при разыменовании которого вы получаете вылет.

Answer (score 0):

В текущей ситуации обращение к памяти контролируется системой с помощью таблицы прав доступа. И если программа пытается модифицировать память чужой программы, то её система сразу завершает без прав отступления. То-есть получает системную ошибку Segmentation fault.
Но данная таблица должна иметь место в памяти и если на каждый байт задавать отдельные права процессам, то памяти будет очень сильно не хватать. Операционные и вычислительные системы работают со страницами памяти.
Система Linux например выделяет 4096 байт минимум и записывает для выделенной страницы права только для текущего процесса.
*Пользоваться памятью текущей страницы вне запрошенного размера всё равно нельзя. Так как компилятор может использовать её по своему усмотрению. На пример храня технические данные выделенной памяти.*

Например выделили память :

```c
A[1] = (double*)calloc(3, sizeof(double));
```

Указатель `A[1]` будет иметь адрес выделенной памяти и доступ `A[1][100]` будет разрешён, так как адреса `A[1][0]` и `A[1][100]` близки и находятся на одной странице памяти.
А если вы хотите изменить `A[100][1]` то может быть ошибка, так как вы указатель никакой не задавали для `A[100] = ?` и там он может быть совершенно случайным.

Answer (score -1):

Ваш код вызывает неопределенное поведение (undefined behavior) при попытке обращения к элементам за пределами выделенного динамического массива. Более конкретно, сегментационная ошибка (segmentation fault) может возникать в случае обращения за пределы памяти, которая выделена для массива.

Почему Segmentation fault не возникает, когда вы выводите содержимое динамического двумерного массива с размерами, большими, чем выделенная память? Это связано с тем, что точное поведение в случае обращения к недопустимой памяти является неопределенным. Компилятор и операционная система могут справляться с этими ситуациями по-разному. Ваш код может продолжать работать и выводить значения, тем самым создавая иллюзию правильной работы, но это неправильное и небезопасное поведение.

Чтобы избежать сегментационной ошибки, важно обращаться только к тем ячейкам памяти, которые были выделены для вашего массива. Если вам нужно использовать массив больших размеров, вы должны выделить достаточное количество памяти и затем обращаться только к ячейкам, находящимся в пределах выделенного блока памяти.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Answer (score -1):

Ваш код для инициализации динамического двумерного массива 3x3 выглядит правильно.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    double** A = (double**)calloc(3, sizeof(double*));
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        A[i] = (double*)calloc(3, sizeof(double));
    }

    // Используйте массив A по вашему усмотрению

    // Освободите память после использования массива
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        free(A[i]);
    }
    free(A);

    return 0;
}
```

После использования массива необходимо освободить память путем вызова free для каждого из выделенных блоков и, наконец, вызова free для самого массива A.